# spring security : managing sssion with live live servers

Tags: spring, spring-security

Hi I am new to spring security. Using 3.1 version.
I have a legacy sso url that asks for username/password and set cookie if user is authenticated.

I am able to authenticate user using custom filter and custom authentication-entry-point.
What I am not able to understand is, suppose my orig request was ../myPage, and customauthentication filter has defaultProcessingUrl ../myFilter, when the user is redirected to my application from custom sso url (assuming I am passing myfilter path as the parameter to legacy sso to redirect after successful authentication), how will original request URL be retreived as I am using servers in live-live mode with non-sticky sessions.

As I understand ExceptionTranslationFilters uses httpsession attribute to save orig url that triggered authentication entry point, but in case of live-live servers redirection could end up on the other server ?

One option is to use "/**" pattern for custom filter and pass orig req to sso lega y url for redirection ? But in this case the logic to create legacy url will be replicated in cutom filter authenticationFailure Handler and custom Authentication point.

any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

Assumption: Your legacy SSO works in different way from like Siteminder (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_management_system)

ExceptionTranslationFilter does not save url that triggered authentication entry point.
It is responsibility of the authentication filter and authentication entry point to manage this.
Please look for example to LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint.
In your case, you should implement your own LegacySSOFilter and LegacySSOEntryPoint.
LegacySSOEntryPoint will redirect to Legacy SSO server and will redirect back to the original application after a user authentication.

Please note, that you should provide a authenticated username to your redirect back to the original application (do it in the secure way)
LegacySSOFilter should take the user name and to authenticate a user similarly to Siteminder filter: http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#d0e6295.

Comment: Thanks for your response Michael. I have changed the approach and now I am using custom pre-auth filter as that seems to be a better fit here.

Comment: Hi Michael, I didn't accepted your answer as I still don't understand how to resolve the issue using custom-auth filter. you mentioned that ExceptionTranslationFilter does not save the url that triggered authentication point, but what I understand is that this filter stores the request in request cache that can be used to get the orig url, but as I have server in live-live mode with non-sticky sessions it cant be guaranteed that request info would be available in cache when user is redirected (as request cache uses httpsession)

Comment: You *can* promote if it was helpful - you *do not* have to. I just looked at ExceptionTranslationFilter source.